# How to resolve these Vimball problems when I install plugins?

Tags: vim, installation

I don't like Vimball files in Vim but more and more plugins use Vimball to install themselves.

A month ago I installed a 64 bits OS and moved my vimfiles directory to **c:\users\"my-name"**
No problem. Everything works fine.

Today I wanted update a plugin (which is now in Vimball).

After sourcing the plugin (`:so %`)
I received a lot of errors:

```
Error detected while processing function vimball#Vimvall..vimball#VimballHome:  
E739: Cannot create directory C:/Progra~1/Vim/vimfiles  
Error detected while processing function vimball# Vimball..<SNR>119_ChgDir:  
E344: Can't find directory "C:\Progra~1\Vim\vimfiles in cdpath  
E472: Command failed
```

...and so a whole page more of these kind of errors.

What's happening and how can I resolve it?

Comment: "more and more plugins use Vimball to install themselves"? Really? I've found most (possibly all) of the plugins I use have moved to a GitHub repository and are easily installable using [**Pathogen**](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen). I'm afraid I've forgotten anything I may have once known about vimballs (I did put one on vim.org way back when, but have also moved to a GitHub-based approach).

Comment: Increasing the verbosity of the startup may help you. See [`:help debug-mode`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#debug-mode) and [`:help :verbose`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:verbose).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vimballs are extracted into the first existing directory on `'runtimepath'`; based on your output, is looks like Vim doesn't recognize the location where you moved your vimfiles to, and instead defaults to the system-wide `C:/Progra~1/Vim/vimfiles` location, which probably is protected by Windows permissions, thereby causing the errors.

Check the output of `:set runtimepath?`; the first component should be your `C:\Users\my-name\vimfiles`; if it isn't, you need to make Vim include it, either via external means (e.g. setting the `HOME` environment variable), or directly in your `~/.vimrc` with `:set runtimepath=...`. See `:help runtimepath` for details.

Also, check for `g:vimball_home`; this Vimball configuration overrides the default logic.

As a workaround (not a solution), you can pass a custom install directory to the `:UseVimball` command.

Comment: The output of set runtimepath? ==>  `runtimepath=~/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim73,C:Program Files (x86)\Vim/vimfiles/after,~/vimfiles/after`  echo $HOME ==> `C:\Users\"Myname"`  When I add `set runtimepath=$HOME\vimfiles` in vimrc set runtimepath? gives as output `runtimepath=~\vimfiles` but still an vimball error: E492: Not an editor command: useVimball

Comment: found it: There was a vimball home directory set at the end of the vimrc. :)

Comment: You mean `g:vimball_home`; yeah, that explains it.